# How to use StructureToPtr with F# Structure? Typeof trouble

Tags: .net, f#, arrays, structure, typeof

I've got structure :

```
type OneDevice = {
        mutable id              : System.UInt16
        mutable typeDev         : byte
        mutable portNum         : byte
        mutable Parity          : byte
        mutable StopBits        : byte
        mutable BaudRate        : byte
        mutable addr1           : byte 
        mutable addr2           : byte 
        mutable useCanal        : byte
        mutable idGroup1        : byte
        mutable idGroup2        : byte 
        mutable idGroup3        : byte
        mutable idGroup4        : byte
        mutable idGroupSos1     : byte 
        mutable idGroupSos2     : byte 
        mutable idGroupSos3     : byte 
        mutable idGroupSos4     : byte 
        mutable idSosReserv     : byte 
        mutable addrModbus      : byte 
        mutable offsetModbus    : System.UInt16
        mutable pwd             : byte array
        mutable offsetInModbus  : System.UInt16
        mutable reserv          : System.UInt16
    }
```

And I need to copy some use it as byte array. In C# I can declare the size of byte array here, but for now I don't know the size of pwd.

I'm trying to use :

```
let memcp(device : OneDevice, bytes : byte array) =
    Array.zeroCreate <| Marshal.SizeOf(typeof<OneDevice>)
        |> fun (array : byte array) ->
        GCHandle.Alloc(array, GCHandleType.Pinned) |> fun handle ->
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(device, handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), true)
            handle.Free()
```

But got error message :

> Error Unable to package type "Model + OneDevice" as an unmanaged
>   structure; impossible to calculate the size or offset that make sense.

I think that is because I don't know the pwd size here. So how can I use it on F# Structure then ? Or maybe I can declare static-size array type somehow ?

*Thank you*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to ensure that the structure you're marshaling has the same layout as the native structure using the `StructLayout` attribute, eg.

```
[<type: StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1, CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)>]
type OneDevice = { 
    ...
```

In addition, you need to explicitly mark any fields with the `MarshalAs` attribute if they require marshaling with non-default marshaling behavior, such as arrays. The default marshaling behavior for arrays is `LPArray`, but by the sounds of it, your native structure is expecting a `ByValArray`.

```
[<field: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 17)>]
mutable pwd             : byte array
```

Lastly, replace `GCHandle.Alloc` with `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` for allocating unmanaged memory, and use `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` to free it.

Note: I'm uncertain whether F# record types can accept these attributes, but I would expect them to work. If not, then you would need to use them in combination with jpalmer's suggestion of using a `struct`.

Edit:

```
let size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof<OneDevice>)
let unmanagedPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size)
Marshal.StructureToPtr(device, unmanagedPtr, false)
Marshal.Copy(unmanagedPtr, bytes, 0, size)
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedPtr)
```

Edit:

The above is for copying a populated OneDevice structure into an empty byte array. If you want to do the reverse - converting a populated byte array into a structure, it's largely the same thing.

```
let size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof<OneDevice>)
let unmanagedPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size)
Marshal.Copy(bytes, unmanagedPtr, 0, size)
Marshal.PtrToStructure(unmanagedPtr, device)
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unmanagedPtr)
```

Comment: ... can you show me how can I replace GCHandle.Alloc with Marshal.AllocHGlobal ? I can't understand how can I make it. It seems like I still need to workaround on it.

Comment: Updated with example. It's straightforward to use - Marshal.Copy will copy the unmanaged buffer into a managed byte array. (Sorry for the imperative style)

Comment: sadly makes no effect :( My structure is still being filled by zero values.

Comment: Are you setting the values of the `device` object before marshalling and copying it? Or was it your intention to do the reverse and convert a byte array to a OneDevice (ie, using `Marshal.PtrToStructure`)?

Comment: I'm trying to fill OneDevice object from byte array. I create empty object first for it (filled with zeros)

Comment: Last edit Works ! the only correction : Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, unmanagedPtr, size)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to creat a struct.  In F# you do this with

```
[<StructAttribute>]
type t = 
    ....
```

Comment: You can have mutable fields in a struct, you just need to use the syntax `val mutable`